# JSTL Form Tag EL Injection

Tags: java, spring, security, jstl, el

I have a security issue. Somebody entered such a value from an input in my web site. The input text is the following:

```
ADMIN{${sleep(20)}}
```

I have a form to select and display those values in a select in my page. However, this value brokes my page. This is my JSP code:

```
<form:select path="roleName" class="form-control">
    <form:option value=""></form:option>
    <c:forEach items="${roleList}" var="role">
        <form:option value="${role.name}"><c:out value="${role.name}" /></form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

`c:out` tag works as expected but `form:option` tag does not work and it throws the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException: no method corresponding to the one declared in the EL was found  method : 'sleep'
  at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.el.FunctionEvaluator.evaluate(FunctionEvaluator.java:65)
  at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.el.ELNode$Function.evaluate(ELNode.java:702)
  at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.el.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl$ELExpression.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.java:188)
  at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.el.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.java:126)
  at org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils.evaluateExpression(ExpressionEvaluationUtils.java:231)
  at org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils.doEvaluate(ExpressionEvaluationUtils.java:206)
  at org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluationUtils.java:94)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.evaluate(AbstractFormTag.java:50)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag.resolveValue(OptionTag.java:247)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag.exposeAttributes(OptionTag.java:174)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.writeTagContent(AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.java:48)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
  at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._user.__listuser._jspService(__listuser.java:968)
```

How can I make `form:option` work to display this weird value? I don't want users to enter those kind of weird values. I want to be able to display what they enter.

EDIT:

The only working solution that I could find is this:

```
<form:select path="roleName" class="form-control">
    <form:option value=""></form:option>
    <c:forEach items="${roleList}" var="role">
        <option value="${fn:escapeXml(role.adi)}" ${role.adi == userSearchForm.roleName ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>
            <c:out value="${role.adi}" />
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

But it seems very ugly.

Comment: What is the expected output? `role.name` should evaluate to `ADMIN{${sleep(20)}}` in your rendered html?

Comment: @minion Yes I want it to be displayed to the user as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can resolve your issue by escaping the values.
example:

```
<form:option value="${fn:escapeXml(role.name)}"><c:out value="${fn:escapeXml(role.name)}" />
```

Comment: No, this does not work. fn:escapeXml escapes xml tags. In my value, I think there is no xml specific character.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to create variable with c:set tag first and then use it in 'value' attribute.

```
<c:set var="roleName"><c:out value="${role.name}" /></c:set>
<form:option value="${roleName}">${roleName}</form:option>
```

Comment: This looks pretty. I will try this 8 hours later when I'm at work.

Answer (score 0):

Since your c:out is working as expected, then one approach would be to use the HTML version of the OPTION tag and leave the *value* attribute off ... so change it to:

```
<c:forEach items="${roleList}" var="role">
    <option><c:out value="${role.name}" /><option>
</c:forEach>
```

The browser will send the *contents* of the option tag over since the *value* attribute was left off.